# Images sticking out past 100 view width are creating an empty white bar on mobile versions

Tags: html, css

A lot of people have said to use overflow hidden on both the parent of the element and the body. But the issue is that the image will be cut off (as desired) however the space it takes up remains. 
Again this only works on mobile where the user can scroll past the view width, or zoom out in a way that browsers cannot

> html, body { max-width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden; }

Has worked for almost every page except one which has a jpeg (don't know if that's relevant) image sticking out:

[White bar example: continues down the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0z6m.png)

Comment: do you have any viewport meta tags on your page?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is the code you tried? Please post **your** CSS and HTML. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi!  As posted above please post your CSS and HTML so we can better understand what your issue is.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The box-sizing property allows us to include the padding and border in an element's total width and height. If you set box-sizing: border-box; on an element padding and border are included in the width and height.

Comment: Why should they try this? What does your answer solve? Without the OPs markup, we're just guessing and that's not what answers are for. This should be a comment.

Comment: Because this sounds like a box-sizing issue =)

Comment: Does it though? Or could it be that they are missing the `viewport` meta tag? Or their images are wider than the viewport and `max-width` is determined by the size of the image and not the browser window? There are so many other things that could be happening that we have no idea about. Side note, I didn't down vote you, but my guess is this answer will continue to get down voted.